# Running a .cgi script via /var/www/cgi-bin in lighttpd web server on raspberry pi

Tags: html, lighttpd, pi

I am following a few year old [tutorial on a web-driven car](https://www.hackster.io/mjrobot/iot-raspberry-pi-robot-with-video-streamer-and-pan-tilt-f50e53)

I have a file structure:

```
/var/

   /www/ (index.html for a webpage with buttons is contained here and displays 
    perfectly)

       /cgi-bin/ (containing cgi scripts with permissions granted)
```

the html code contains functions calling the scripts from /cgi-bin/:

```
function centertilt()
{
    xmlhttp.open("GET","cgi-bin/centertilt.cgi",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and buttons calling those functions

```
button {
        color: blue;
        background:lightgrey;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 8px;
        position: center;
}
         ...
<button style="height: 50px; width: 100px; font-size: 25px" onclick="centertilt()">0</button>
         ...
```

When I run the .cgi scripts via the CLI they work perfectly but the buttons don't call them when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a path beginning with '/' in the CGI URL?

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/cgi-bin/centertilt.cgi",true);
```

Have you looked in the lighttpd error log for errors, or looked in the lighttpd access log to see what is being requested?